# how to make thumbnails of images or how to find the path to the image java

Tags: java, image, path, get, thumbnails

I have 2 panels connected with drag & drop

http://i43.tinypic.com/k3m4xs.jpg

In the left panel i created JLabels with small pictures like that:

```
ImageIcon ico =new ImageIcon("C:\\Documents and Settings\\student\\workspace\\DragTest3\\src\\drzewo.png");;
    p1.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon(ico.getDescription())).getImage()).getScaledInstance(30, 30, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))));
```

code after dropping JLabel:

```
ImageIcon ico = (ImageIcon)src.draggingLabel.getIcon();     
label=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon(ico.getImage()).getImage()).getScaledInstance(60, 60, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))));
```

but in my Image on right panel i see pixels.

**It's possible get orginal path to this image?
Or any idea how I can zoom my ImageIcon on JLabel?**

I might add that I have not found a solution in this forum, despite similar questions so please don't hold my ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the original path with the label somehow, most likely by creating your own sub-class of label that stores the path inside it. You can then query the path from the label when you get the drop event.

You can also look at using `ImageIO` to load into a `BufferedImage` which then gives you much more power and control over the image.

Comment: so when i do something like that: ' ImageIcon ico = (ImageIcon)src.draggingLabel.getIcon();
       BufferedImage imgg= (BufferedImage)ico.getImage();'
Now it's possible get path from BufferedImage?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html   do you see a getPath method?

Comment: BufferedImages represent images, they could have come from anywhere or even been generated dynamically. They don't have path or file information in them.